# Linux-Live-system inc. Ruby 1.9 on USB-Stick with r/w-Partition

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, usb

well guess that many of you have great expertise on Linux. I currently have some issues with creating a linux-live-medium.

i have a box with OpenSuse-Linux Version 11.3 with all nice things. Several languages run very well: Perl, Python, PHP! All is very well! BTW - i am very glad that Perl runs very nice.

But I am not able to install Ruby 1.9. Everytime i want to do that i end up with Ruby 1.8.7. I want to testrun some ruby-code. Therefore i need Ruby with the following gems

mechanize
nokogiri
utf8_utils

I heard of a Linux-Live-medium that is able to run with all the wanted things including Ruby 1.9. 
Therefore the Live-medium is installed on a USB-Stick with R/W partitions. Is this possible.

I am not a linux-expert - but with all the expertise here i think it is possible to create such a USB-Stick. (...with Ruby 1.9 and all with all that extensions)
I love to hear from you!

best regards
zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu includes both Ruby 1.8.x and 1.9.x - and essentially duplicates most packages in 2 flavors: for 1.8 and 1.9. That might be enough for your purposes - although YMMV, of course.

Yet another solution is RVM that karudzo already mentioned.

Yet another solution is virtualization: simplest form of it would be just chrooting. Most modern Linux systems have an ability to install itself based from some root directory (SuSE has [install into given directory](https://features.opensuse.org/306753) functionality, Debian/Ubuntu have [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) - and then just running `chroot /path/to/that/directory` - you'd end up in essentially another system installed cleanly in separate directory.

Comment: helloo GreyCat! - many many  thanks for your advices! i am going to read your adviced papers. I am  just abeginner, but this helps me alot! I am glad that there  is a solution!!! THX zero

Answer (score 1):

This will actually be a better solution for you- use RVM:

- https://rvm.io/

Then you can easily switch back and forth from 1.8 to 1.9 as desired and make 1.9.2 your default.  Just read their docs carefully, it really makes gem management a lot easier.

Comment: helloo karudzo - many many  thanks! i am going to read your adviced papers. I am glad that there  is a solution!!! THX zero